# In bash script, what happens when a signal is trapped

Tags: bash, shell

Suppose I am running the following example saved as `hello.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
hello() {
    echo "hello"
}

trap "hello" INT
sleep 100
echo "end"
```

and in shell I start `hello.sh`. After 1 second I press `Ctrl-C`.

Please treat `sleep` as any long-run process that I started.

Here are my questions:

1. When `SIGINT` is generated, is it delivered to `sleep` directly or to the shell script?
2. If it is the second, can I let `sleep` has a chance to handle the `SIGINT` and do not propagate to its parent `hello.sh`?
3. If it is the first, what is the status of `sleep` after the `hello` function is finished?

My tests made me feel that the following occurred in order

1. `sleep` started to run
2. `hello.sh` received the signal
3. function `hello` started to run
4. function `hello` finished
5. `echo "end"` started to run
6. the script exits.

But at which stage the `sleep` process exits and because of what (e.g. the SIGINT stopped the `sleep` process?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
$ cat foo.sh
_sigint()
{
    echo "received SIGINT"
}

trap _sigint INT

sleep 10000
echo "status=$?"
$ bash foo.sh              # <-- start foo.sh and then press CTRL-C
^Creceived SIGINT
status=130
```

Some explanation:

- `sleep` runs as a child process of `bash`. `bash` and `sleep` are running in the same *process group* which is now the *foreground process group*.
- When <kbd>CTRT-C</kbd> is pressed, it'll generate `SIGINT` and the signal will be sent to **all** processes in the *foreground process group* so **both** `bash` and `sleep` will receive `SIGINT`.
- According to bash [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) <sup>(can also see `man bash`)</sup>

  > If bash is waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal for which a trap has  been  set,  the  trap will  not  be  executed **until the command completes**.

  So here `bash` would wait for `sleep` to be killed <sup>(The default SIGINT behavior is to terminate the process. See [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html))</sup> first and then `bash` runs its `SIGINT` trap.
- According to bash manaul

  > The return value of a simple command is its exit status, or `128+n` if the command is terminated by signal `n`.

  The `SIGINT` is 2 <sup>(see `kill -l`)</sup> so `sleep`'s exit status is `128+2=130`.

Comment: it involves quite some unix/linux knowledge. you can refer to, for example, [APUE3e](http://www.apuebook.com/about3e.html)'s Chapter 9 (Process Releationships) and Chapter 10 (Signals).

Comment: Does it mean the following happens in sequence: 1. sleep is killed by SIGINT. 2. bash runs `_sigint`, 3. bash runs `echo "status=$?"`?

Comment: @panda yes your sequence is correct.